# Are there tricks and tweaks for unevaluated integrals in SymPy?

Tags: python, sympy, integral

I try to verify some formula from a paper concerning mechanics by retracing their derivation, involving some integrals like these:

[image: an example integral]

The original source suggests that the solution is possible, but it seems quite tricky. I tried my best with SymPy (also with Maxima and Mathematica) fiddling around with different assumptions and simplifications, without any success:

```
import sympy as sp
from IPython.display import display, Math

x = sp.symbols('x', nonnegative=True, real=True, finite=True)
a = sp.symbols('a', positive=True, real=True, finite=True)
b = sp.symbols('b', positive=True, real=True, finite=True)
# print("assumptions for x:", x.assumptions0)
# print("assumptions for a, b:", r.assumptions0)

expr = x/(b + 2*(a-sp.sqrt(x)*sp.sqrt(2*a-x)))**3
expr = sp.expand(expr)
display(Math("e = "+sp.latex(expr)))

integ = sp.integrate(expr, (x, 0, a))
display(Math("integ = "+sp.latex(integ)))
```

SymPy returns my integrals unevaluated. Are there any other tricks and tweaks I could try to get a solution? The parameter a and b are physical dimensions (finite positive real numbers).

Comment: I'd start by trying particular simple values for `a` and `b`. If it can't be done for numeric values then a result in terms of the symbolic parameters is unlikely.

Comment: I believe the `integrate` docs talk mostly about trying various heuristics, seeking an anti-derivative.  That's basically the same way we calculated integrals in calculus class.  There parameters that can help guide that search, aren't there?

Comment: @hpaulj: Not really, as far as I understand. The parameters mentioned in the [reference](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/integrals/integrals.html#sympy.integrals.integrals.integrate) seam to limit the used strategies and do not guide the search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer found using [Rubi](https://rulebasedintegration.org/) is

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
(a^2*(2*a + b)^4*(Sqrt[2*a - Sqrt[-4*a - b]*Sqrt[b]]*Sqrt[2*a + Sqrt[-4*a - b]*Sqrt[b]]*
    (Sqrt[b]*(-2*a + b)*Sqrt[-(4*a + b)^2] + 6*a*Sqrt[-4*a - b]*(2*a + b)*ArcTan[(2*a)/(Sqrt[b]*Sqrt[4*a + b])]) - 
   6*a*(2*a + b)^2*Sqrt[4*a + b]*ArcTanh[Sqrt[2*a - Sqrt[-4*a - b]*Sqrt[b]]/Sqrt[2*a + Sqrt[-4*a - b]*Sqrt[b]]] + 
   6*a*(2*a + b)^2*Sqrt[4*a + b]*ArcTanh[Sqrt[2*a + Sqrt[-4*a - b]*Sqrt[b]]/Sqrt[2*a - Sqrt[-4*a - b]*Sqrt[b]]]))/
 (2*(2*a - Sqrt[-4*a - b]*Sqrt[b])^(5/2)*(2*a + Sqrt[-4*a - b]*Sqrt[b])^(5/2)*Sqrt[-4*a - b]*b^(5/2)*(4*a + b)^(5
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That solves my problem. I hope Rubi is successfully incorporated into SymPy (in progress I think), so there is some open-source-software around, able to handle stuff like that - What a great project.